# Launch most recent app

Tags: android, activity-manager

I'm working on a productivity app and I would like to be able to launch the users most recent app when a gesture is detected, however, I can't figure out why this code below isn't launching my most recent app.

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
RecentTaskInfo task = m.getRecentTasks(1, 0).get(0);
startActivity(task.baseIntent);
```

I also have this permission in my manifest

```
android.permission.GET_TASKS
```

Thank you for any help as to why this isn't working

Comment: do you see any errors in the `LogCat`?

Comment: I only saw the missing permission but then I added that and it still didn't work. But will look through the logs some more even though I didn't find anything last time

Comment: does this happen with only a specific app or with all the apps?

Comment: Its quite possibly working. `m.getRecentTasks(1, 0).get(0);` will try to launch/bring to foreground the first task, which is the one currently on screen(including homescreen). Change the maximum numbers of tasks returned. Open a bunch of apps, try `m.getRecentTasks(2, 0).get(1);`.

Comment: Hmm that makes a lot of sense I will try it when I get back to my laptop thanks for the tip

Comment: @user2558882 you were right on the money dunno why that wasn't obvious but it's working now thanks a million

Comment: Alright, you're welcome. Posted an answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RecentTaskInfo task = m.getRecentTasks(1, 0).get(0);
```

Since you are setting max number of results to `1`, you are getting your own task with `get(0)`. To get the result you are looking for, try setting the max # of results to `2` and use the second task from the returned list:

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
RecentTaskInfo task = m.getRecentTasks(2, 0).get(1);
startActivity(task.baseIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me to get recent 30 apps:

```
    private static final int MAX_TASKS = 30;

    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


    final List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks =
                am.getRecentTasks(MAX_TASKS,                   ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
```